# Iterative filtering in R

Tags: r, dplyr, iteration, filtering

I have a dataset of patient visits at a clinic. Each individual patient can visit on multiple occasions. Each patient is identified by a study_id and each visit by an illness_id. I want to iteratively filter the dataframe so that a visit that occurs within 28 days of a previous visit is removed.

I cannot simply calculate the interval between all visits and then remove those which occur within 28 days. The intervals need to be calculated iteratively as the dataframe is filtered.

In the example below you can see patient 0003 presented three times. Visit 1 is always retained. Visit 2 should be removed as it occurred 7 days after Visit 1. Once Visit 2 is removed, Visit 3 would occur 29 days after Visit 1 and so should be retained. However if I calculate all the intervals and then filter out any visits with an interval of 28 days or less, both Visits 2 and 3 would be removed (because Visit 2 occurred 7 days after Visit 1 and Visit 3 occurred 22 days after Visit 2).

| study_id | illness_id | illness_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 000103/12/2007 | 2007/12/03 |
| 0002 | 000224/03/2008 | 2008/03/24 |
| 0002 | 000226/04/2008 | 2008/04/26 |
| 0002 | 000217/07/2008 | 2008/07/17 |
| 0002 | 000221/08/2008 | 2008/08/21 |
| 0002 | 000225/08/2008 | 2008/08/25 |
| 0003 | 000329/09/2008 | 2008/09/29 |
| 0003 | 000306/10/2008 | 2008/10/06 |
| 0003 | 000328/10/2008 | 2008/10/28 |

The correctly filtered dataframe should be:

| study_id | illness_id | illness_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 000103/12/2007 | 2007/12/03 |
| 0002 | 000224/03/2008 | 2008/03/24 |
| 0002 | 000226/04/2008 | 2008/04/26 |
| 0002 | 000217/07/2008 | 2008/07/17 |
| 0002 | 000221/08/2008 | 2008/08/21 |
| 0003 | 000329/09/2008 | 2008/09/29 |
| 0003 | 000328/10/2008 | 2008/10/28 |

Thanks for any help - I am new to R and am struggling to get my head around iteration and loops. If there is a simple solution involving dplyr filter that would be great.

---

**IN RESPONSE TO SOME SUGGESTIONS BELOW I AM POSTING ANOTHER EXAMPLE TO TRY AND MAKE THE QUESTION CLEARER**

The 'comparator' row cannot be fixed at the first visit for each patient. It needs to roll through the dataframe as the filtering is done iteratively. Sorry if this was not clear in the OP. Here is an eg where rows 2, 3 and 5 should be removed, and rows 1, 4 and 6 should be retained.

Row 2 is 8 days after row 1, so is removed. Row 3 is 26 days after row 1, so is removed. Row 4 is 41 days after row 1, so is retained and becomes the comparator for subsequent visits for this patient. Row 5 is 6 days after row 4, so is removed. Row 6 is  31 days after row 4 so is retained and becomes the comparator for subsequent visits for this patient.

| study_id | illness_id | illness_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 000119/12/2007 | 19/12/2007 |
| 0001 | 000127/12/2007 | 27/12/2007 |
| 0001 | 000114/01/2008 | 14/01/2008 |
| 0001 | 000129/01/2008 | 29/01/2008 |
| 0001 | 000104/02/2008 | 04/02/2008 |
| 0001 | 000129/02/2008 | 29/02/2008 |

**Here is the v elegant solution provided by @sbarbit** - sincere thanks!!

```
df1 <- df |>
arrange(study_id, illness_date) |> 
mutate(comparator = purrr::accumulate(illness_date,~ifelse(.y - .x > 28, .y,.x))) |>
mutate(daydiff = illness_date - lag(comparator, 1,0)) |>
mutate(daydiff = as.numeric(daydiff)) |>
filter(daydiff > 28)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I use `purrr::accumulate` to propagate only dates that are more than 28 days from the preceding date, otherwise keep the preceding date. Then, rows are filtered based on the comparison with the updated preceding row.

DATA:

```r
df <- data.frame(illness_id = c("000103/12/2007",
                                "000224/03/2008",
                                "000226/04/2008",
                                "000217/07/2008",
                                "000221/08/2008",
                                "000225/08/2008",
                                "000329/09/2008",
                                "000306/10/2008",
                                "000328/10/2008"),

                 illness_date = as.Date(c("2007/12/03",
                                          "2008/03/24",
                                          "2008/04/26",
                                          "2008/07/17",
                                          "2008/08/21",
                                          "2008/08/25",
                                          "2008/09/29",
                                          "2008/10/06",
                                          "2008/10/28"),
                                       format  = "%Y/%m/%d"),

                 study_id = c("0001",
                              "0002",
                              "0002",
                              "0002",
                              "0002",
                              "0002",
                              "0003",
                              "0003",
                              "0003"))
```

Here I show the algorithm without the filtering step to illustrate how it works:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df |>
  group_by(study_id) |>
  arrange(illness_date, by_group = TRUE) |>
  mutate(comparator = purrr::accumulate(illness_date,~ifelse(.y - .x > 28, .y,.x))) |>
  mutate(daydiff = illness_date - lag(comparator, 1,0))

+ # A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   study_id [3]
  illness_id     illness_date study_id comparator daydiff
  <chr>          <date>       <chr>         <dbl>   <dbl>
1 000103/12/2007 2007-12-03   0001          13850   13850
2 000224/03/2008 2008-03-24   0002          13962   13962
3 000226/04/2008 2008-04-26   0002          13995      33
4 000217/07/2008 2008-07-17   0002          14077      82
5 000221/08/2008 2008-08-21   0002          14112      35
6 000225/08/2008 2008-08-25   0002          14112       4
7 000329/09/2008 2008-09-29   0003          14151   14151
8 000306/10/2008 2008-10-06   0003          14151       7
9 000328/10/2008 2008-10-28   0003          14180      29
```

Here I add the filtering step:

```r
df |>
  group_by(study_id) |>
  arrange(illness_date, by_group = TRUE) |>
  mutate(comparator = purrr::accumulate(illness_date,~ifelse(.y - .x > 28, .y,.x))) |>
  mutate(daydiff = illness_date - lag(comparator, 1,0)) |>
  filter(daydiff > 28)

# A tibble: 7 x 5
# Groups:   study_id [3]
  illness_id     illness_date study_id comparator daydiff
  <chr>          <date>       <chr>         <dbl>   <dbl>
1 000103/12/2007 2007-12-03   0001          13850   13850
2 000224/03/2008 2008-03-24   0002          13962   13962
3 000226/04/2008 2008-04-26   0002          13995      33
4 000217/07/2008 2008-07-17   0002          14077      82
5 000221/08/2008 2008-08-21   0002          14112      35
6 000329/09/2008 2008-09-29   0003          14151   14151
7 000328/10/2008 2008-10-28   0003          14180      29
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am not exactly sure how the ifelse part of the code is working but overall this solution does not work as rows that are <= 28 days from the preceding visit remain in the dataframe. I have added another example to the OP to try and give some further clarity. Thank you.

Comment: @arji_barji May be the description of the code was not optimal. I edited it to add clarity. Did you try it out on an actual dataframe or are you assuming that it won't work based on the description of the algorithm? It seems to me that does exactly what you want. Can you post a dataframe (attaching  `dput(df)` to your OP) that will fail?

Comment: huge thxs for clear explanation. Works perfectly! :) I made minor change to arrange fx to keep df in correct order (and converted daydiff to numeric to help crosscheck) but this is v elegant soln! I'm not 100% sure what "~ifelse(.y - .x > 28, .y,.x)" does? Can u explain syntax if u hve time?

Comment: @arji_barji the formula syntax e.g. `~ .x + 2` is a compact way to define a function that is accepted in tidyverse (see [this](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/as_function.html)). It is equivalent to `function(a,b) ifelse(b - a > 28, b, a)`

Comment: (+1) Nice use of accumulate! This seems like a useful pattern to keep in mind. One suggestion: With "comparator" here, I think what you are finding is the start of an unbroken streak of dates within 28 days. Since the interval length is already baked into this, the filtering by the same difference later is a bit redundant. Instead, you could just filter on the current date being different from the streak start, i.e. `illness_date != comparator`.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila You're right, you could use `illness_date != comparator` with the same effect and possibly more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(illness_date = as.Date(illness_date, 
                                format = "%Y/%m/%d")) %>% 
  group_by(study_id) %>% 
  mutate(time_since_first_visit = illness_date - min(illness_date)) %>% 
  filter(time_since_first_visit == 0 | time_since_first_visit > 28)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Sadly this will not work because the comparator row cannot be fixed as the first visit but needs to "roll" through the dataframe as the filtering is done iteratively. Apologies if this was not clear in the OP. I have added another example about to try and make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that returns the rows to drop and an example of calling it by group using `data.table`.

```
fFilter <- function(v, gap) {
  blnDrop <- logical(length(v))
  if (length(v) > 1L) {
    prev <- v[1]
    
    for (i in 2:length(v)) {
      if (v[i] - prev <= gap) blnDrop[i] <- TRUE else prev <- v[i]
    }
  }
  
  blnDrop
}

library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(id = rep(1:3, c(1, 5, 3)), date = as.Date(c("2007/12/3", "2008/3/24", "2008/4/26", "2008/7/17", "2008/8/21", "2008/8/25", "2008/9/29", "2008/10/6", "2008/10/28")))
setorder(dt, id, date)
dt[,drop := fFilter(date, 28), by = "id"][drop == FALSE, 1:(length(dt) - 1L)]
#>    id       date
#> 1:  1 2007-12-03
#> 2:  2 2008-03-24
#> 3:  2 2008-04-26
#> 4:  2 2008-07-17
#> 5:  2 2008-08-21
#> 6:  3 2008-09-29
#> 7:  3 2008-10-28
```